# Regex number of spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a strings "Peugeot 208 1.6HDi192 TGK Confort" or "Renault Clio III 1.5DCi75 AC-Tem" but i need only "Peugeot 208 1.6HDi192" and "Renault Clio III 1.5DCi75".
I need know number of spaces cc99 or cc999 (c=character).

Ty for help.

Comment: Anything you've tried? What did not work? Also your desired output is inconsistent as far as spaces are concerned.

Comment: Nope i not tried anything. I'm a beginner in the world of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each car fits the same type of formatting, this expression would work for you:

[`(.*?\d\.\d[A-Za-z]{3}\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/yk2oIl/3)

Comment: Ty for help i try.